# Topic modeling with word embeddings

Tags: data-science, gensim, lda, word-embedding, topic-modeling

I am currently trying to create an LDA model with word embeddings. Here is the code:

```
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec

# Convert the text object into a list of sentences
sentences = [' '.join(doc) for doc in texts]

# Train the word2vec model to get word embeddings
model_w2v = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)

# Create a dictionary and corpus for the LDA model
dictionary = Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

# Reshape the word embeddings to match the shape expected by the LDA model
word_embeddings = model_w2v.wv.vectors
num_words = len(dictionary)
num_topics = 10
eta = np.zeros((num_words, num_topics))
for i, word in enumerate(dictionary):
    if word in model_w2v.wv.key_to_index:
        idx = model_w2v.wv.key_to_index[word]
        eta[i, :] = model_w2v.wv.vectors[idx]

# Transpose eta to match the expected shape
eta = eta.T

# Train the LDA model using the reshaped word embeddings
lda_model = LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                     id2word=dictionary,
                     num_topics=num_topics,
                     passes=10,
                     alpha='auto',
                     eta=eta)

# Print the topics generated by the LDA model
for topic in lda_model.show_topics():
    print(topic)
```

the texts object is a list of lists that consists of sublists of documents that I've already preprocessed. For some reason my code produces topics that are basically the same:

```
(1, '0.019*"benefit" + 0.017*"include" + 0.017*"plan" + 0.013*"supplier" + 0.012*"experience" + 0.011*"team" + 0.010*"business" + 0.010*"ability" + 0.010*"other" + 0.010*"management"')
(2, '0.019*"product" + 0.017*"customer" + 0.016*"work" + 0.010*"experience" + 0.010*"sale" + 0.009*"team" + 0.008*"business" + 0.007*"company" + 0.007*"management" + 0.006*"opportunity"')
(3, '0.032*"product" + 0.017*"team" + 0.016*"experience" + 0.014*"work" + 0.012*"customer" + 0.008*"business" + 0.007*"build" + 0.007*"more" + 0.006*"drive" + 0.006*"company"')
(4, '0.017*"product" + 0.013*"include" + 0.013*"work" + 0.012*"experience" + 0.012*"team" + 0.010*"benefit" + 0.008*"other" + 0.007*"customer" + 0.007*"pay" + 0.007*"program"')
(5, '0.035*"product" + 0.022*"team" + 0.017*"experience" + 0.015*"user" + 0.010*"work" + 0.010*"ability" + 0.009*"company" + 0.009*"program" + 0.009*"datum" + 0.009*"drive"')
(6, '0.017*"product" + 0.015*"experience" + 0.013*"team" + 0.012*"work" + 0.009*"project" + 0.009*"include" + 0.009*"marketing" + 0.008*"development" + 0.007*"business" + 0.007*"other"')
(7, '0.016*"product" + 0.014*"work" + 0.012*"team" + 0.010*"project" + 0.010*"experience" + 0.010*"new" + 0.009*"development" + 0.008*"support" + 0.007*"service" + 0.007*"year"')
(8, '0.015*"experience" + 0.015*"product" + 0.014*"project" + 0.011*"management" + 0.011*"team" + 0.011*"support" + 0.010*"include" + 0.009*"work" + 0.009*"system" + 0.009*"ensure"')
(9, '0.014*"work" + 0.013*"experience" + 0.011*"team" + 0.011*"datum" + 0.011*"security" + 0.009*"study" + 0.008*"product" + 0.008*"design" + 0.007*"development" + 0.007*"customer"')
```

I am obviously doing something wrong here. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your attempt to use word-vectors as an input to the LDA process, via the `eta` parameter.

Are you following a successful recipe from somewhere? What advantage are you expecting from this non-standard approach? What was wrong with usual LDA?

It looks like you're passing a bad corpus – where each text is a space-delimited string – into `Word2Vec`. It expects each text to be a list-of-words. By passing strings (lists-of-single-characters), the only 'words' learned by your model are likely just single-characters, which aren't useful as word-vectors, much less an input to a later LDA process.

(Have you examined the `model_w2v` for sensible contents before trying to use its results? Have you run with logging at the INFO level & watched all output for sensible progress-reporting?)

It's essentially a never good idea to use `min_count=1` with `Word2Vec` training. Words with just one (or a few) examples in the corpus won't get good vectors from so litle data – but they often make other word-vectors worse, compared to ignoring rare words completely (like the default `min_count=5` does).

I don't see how the (default `vector_size`) 100-dimensional word vectors are going to be any use in your `eta`. (In fact, trying to simulate your code with my own plug data, I get `numpy` broadcast errors rather than any successful initialization of `eta` when trying to assign different-width vectors into it.)

Why would the 100 dimensions of a dense word-embedding – which each alone typically *don't* have any clean easily-interpretable meaning – be useful hints to an LDA word-to-topic mapping with only 10 topics & some arbitrary number of words?

Answer (score 0):

There exist frameworks which perform topic modelling on embedding spaces combining word2vec with lda variational inference. E.g. ETM https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels.etm/index.html